# Core Graphics drawing a square result in rectangle

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a square in my context, but it results in a rectangle with a short and longer side. (in my ipad retina simulator)

This is part of the drawRect method of my view object:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat minx = 0;
CGFloat maxx = 45 - 1;
CGFloat miny = 0;
CGFloat maxy = 45 - 1;

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, maxy);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, minx, miny);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, maxx, miny);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, maxx, miny);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, maxx, maxy);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, minx, maxy);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to set an aspect ratio or something?

Edit:
I found out that

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, 0.75f);
```

makes the result square again, but the end result is not spot on.
Does anybody know why I need to correct the vertical scale?

Comment: Where are you getting the context from? Are you resizing the view after you do the drawing? What does the output look exactly?

Comment: If you are not resizing the context elsewhere, then this is most likely due to your monitor's resolution setting being out-of-whack with aspect ratio.

Comment: I'm getting the context from within my views drawRect method. I am not doing anything after that. The output looks like a rectangle. And my monitor is not out of wack, nor is my iPads screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it....

Turns out I was modifying the views rect elsewhere.
Disabled that, and now my squares are square again.

Thanks for the hint Ismael !!